# Visual Studio jQuery IntelliSense fix KB958502 does not recognize visual studio 2008 install on windows server 2008 x64

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-server-2008, intellisense

So just this week I had the opportunity to re-build my development machine and I opted to use **Windows Server 2008 x64** version for my operating system. I re-installed **Visual Studio 2008** along with all of my other development tools. I surprised to see that the [**KB958502 hot fix**](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB958502/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1736) did not recognize my installation of **Visual Studio 2008**. I wonder if there is a solution to this or if there is an alternative means of manually enabling **jQuery** intellisense.

Thank you.

**Update**:
[Stuart Dunkeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43846/stuart-dunkeld) was correct I forgot to install [**Visual Studio 2008 SP1**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you installed Visual Studio 2008 SP1, which is a prerequisite for this hotfix? See also [this page](http://mwtech.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-get-jquery-intellisense-working.html)..

Comment: Doh, sure enough you were correct I thought I had installed Visual Studio SP1.

Answer (score 1):

If you tried these : [jQuery Intellisense in VS 2008](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/21/jquery-intellisense-in-vs-2008.aspx)  and  [Add reference to javascript file](http://igurr.com/blogs/programming/archive/2009/02/22/add-reference-to-javascript-file.aspx)  and no hope, so try to add this line in the first line of your JS file:

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js" />
```

And make sure [jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/downloads/detail?name=jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js) file is in the same directory of your JS file.